# Looping XML with element using xmlReader

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing, xmlreader

```
   Dim client As New WebClient()
   Dim xmlString As String = client.DownloadString("http://api.rovicorp.com/TVlistings/v9/listings/gridschedule/80000/info?locale=en-US&duration=220&includechannelimages=1&format=xml&apikey=" & api_TV)
   Dim counter As Integer = 0

Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(xmlString))
    Dim tvListings As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)

    For Each blah As XElement In tvListings.Root.Elements
        counter += 1
    Next

    Debug.Print(counter)
End Using
```

And i only get a **counter** of 8 which should be around 100+.

The XML looks like this:

```
<GetGridScheduleResult xmlns="http://api.rovicorp.com/v9/listings" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Locale="en-US" ServiceId="5122" Name="Cityhere - Comcast" StartDate="2013-04-12T14:18:24.2054325Z" Duration="240">
<GridChannels>
  <GridChannel ServiceId="890138" SourceId="1280" Order="20002" Channel="2" CallLetters="WGNAMER" DisplayName="WGNAMER" SourceLongName="WGN America" Type="24-Hours" SourceType="Basic" ParentNetworkId="0" IconAvailable="false" IsChannelOverride="false" SourceAttributes="0">
    <ChannelSchedules/>
    <SourceAttributeTypes/>
    <Airings>
        <GridAiring ProgramId="35951" SeriesId="3490" Title="Matlock" EpisodeTitle="Santa Claus" AiringTime="2013-04-12T14:00:00Z" Duration="60" Color="Color" AiringType="Unknown" CC="true" LetterBox="false" Stereo="false" HD="false" SAP="false" TVRating="TV-PG" Dolby="false" DSS="false" HDLevel="HD Level Unknown" DVS="false" Category="Other" Subcategory="drama" Sports="false"/>
        <GridAiring ProgramId="828869" SeriesId="1409" Title="In the Heat of the Night" EpisodeTitle="Hatton's Turn" AiringTime="2013-04-12T15:00:00Z" Duration="60" Color="Color" AiringType="Unknown" CC="true" LetterBox="false" Stereo="false" HD="false" SAP="false" TVRating="TV-PG@V" Dolby="false" DSS="false" HDLevel="HD Level Unknown" DVS="false" Category="Other" Subcategory="crime drama" Sports="false"/>
        <GridAiring ProgramId="978338" SeriesId="1409" Title="In the Heat of the Night" EpisodeTitle="Hatton's Turn" AiringTime="2013-04-12T16:00:00Z" Duration="60" Color="Color" AiringType="Unknown" CC="true" LetterBox="false" Stereo="false" HD="false" SAP="false" TVRating="TV-PG@V" Dolby="false" DSS="false" HDLevel="HD Level Unknown" DVS="false" Category="Other" Subcategory="crime drama" Sports="false"/>
        <GridAiring ProgramId="4210626" Title="WGN Midday News" AiringTime="2013-04-12T17:00:00Z" Duration="60" Color="Color" AiringType="New" CC="true" LetterBox="false" Stereo="true" HD="false" SAP="false" TVRating="None" Dolby="false" DSS="false" HDLevel="HD Level Unknown" DVS="false" Category="News" Subcategory="newscast" Sports="false"/>
        <GridAiring ProgramId="878716" SeriesId="1028666" Title="Walker, Texas Ranger" EpisodeTitle="El Coyote, Part 2" AiringTime="2013-04-12T18:00:00Z" Duration="60" Color="Color" AiringType="Unknown" CC="true" LetterBox="false" Stereo="true" HD="false" SAP="false" TVRating="TV-14@V" Dolby="false" DSS="false" HDLevel="HD Level Unknown" DVS="false" Category="Other" Subcategory="crime drama" Sports="false"/>
    </Airings>
    <ChannelImages>
        <ImageGrid ImageUrl="http://cps-static.rovicorp.com/2/Open/TV%20Guide%20Widget%20Logos/WGN_2010.png" ImageId="427700" ImageTitle="WGN America" ImageCaption="Widget Logo" ObjectId="1280" ObjectName="WGN America" ImageCreditDisplay="false" ImageType="Station Logo" ImageHorizontalResolution="92" ImageVerticalResolution="36" ImageFormatId="0" AspectRatio="5:2" ParentImageId="16818227">
            <ObjectType>Source</ObjectType>
            <ImageFormat xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ImageExpiryDateTime xsi:nil="true"/>
            <LastUpdate>2012-01-24T15:20:46.453Z</LastUpdate>
        </ImageGrid>
    </ChannelImages>
  </GridChannel>
  etc etc...
</GridChannels>
</GetGridScheduleResult>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is more than 8 `<GridChannels>` elements withing your document? Remember that `Elements()` method return only direct child of current element, so you're counting number of elements that are direct child of `Root` element, which is `GetGridScheduleResult` in your XML.

Comment: Where did xmlstring magically appear from?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson updated OP to show that.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek postive. Its a tv listing that has 300+ channels.

Comment: Perhaps you could `Debug.Print()` the 8 nodes you are successfully counting to get some more symptom info.

Comment: Set breakpoint inside the loop and inspect `blah` variable. VS has an XML view for your convenience. BTW, you don't need `XmlReader` here.

Comment: Can you clarify what output you expect to better help you achieve it? Is it GrindChannels you are counting?

Comment: Get rid of the XmlReader you aren't using it

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I am using the xmlReader within the **Using**. I'm only using the **XmlReader** to see how many times it needs to loop.

Comment: @StealthRT, Xdocumemt.parse will give you that, and seeing as it's using the entire doc anyway using XmlReader is pointless.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson regardless i still can not get it to loop through all the elements.

Comment: You still haven't said what you mean by all elements. If you mean every xmlNode despite the nesting, that's not how xml works and you are doing something well wrong.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Meaning every instant of **GridChannel** which houses each channel information. There should be over 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it by doing this:

```
    Dim jsonObject As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(s)

    For Each post In jsonObject.GridScheduleResult.GridChannels
        Dim Channel As String = post.Channel
        Dim DisplayName As String = post.DisplayName

        If post.ChannelImages.Count <> 0 Then
            Dim ImageUrl As String = post.ChannelImages.Item(0).ToString
            Dim tmpL As Integer = InStr(ImageUrl, ":")
            Dim tmpR As Integer = InStr(ImageUrl, ",")
        End If

        While counter < post.Airings.Count
            Dim Title As String = post.Airings.Item(counter).Title
            Dim EpisodeTitle As String = post.Airings.Item(counter).EpisodeTitle
        End While

        theTime = 0
        counter = 0
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a count of `<GridChannel>` elements then all you need is a small LINQ statement

c#

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(XmlString);
var count = document.Descendants("GridChannel").Count();
```

VB.Net

```
Dim document as XDocument = XDocument.Parse(XmlString)
Dim count = document.Descendants("GridChannel").Count()
```

Comment: The count is 0 it says. **Dim count = blah.Descendants("GridChannel").Count()**

Comment: Could it be because **GridChannel** is not set up like this **<GridChannel>** and its **<GridChannel ServiceId="890138" SourceId="1280" Order="20002" Channel="2" CallLetters="WGNAMER" DisplayName="WGNAMER" SourceLongName="WGN America" Type="24-Hours" SourceType="Basic" ParentNetworkId="0" IconAvailable="false" IsChannelOverride="false" SourceAttributes="0">**

Comment: No the attributes and child elements shouldn't matter. Is your XML identical to above, including case? I tested against the above and got results. If you are loading from a file rather than a string variable use XDocument.Load("pathtofile")

Comment: I'm still coming up with **0** for count.
Dim tvListings As XDocument = XDocument.Load("c:\temp\xml.xml")
Dim count = tvListings.Descendants("GridChannel").Count()

Comment: Is your xml formed properly? Including XML declaration at the top?

Answer (score 0):

Try this then

```
Dim doc as XmlDocument =  new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString)
XmlNode channelsNode = doc.documentElement.SelectSingleNode("GridChannels")
foreach XmlNode gridChannelNode in channelsNode.SelectNodes("GridChannel"))
///
Next
```

Given what you've posted, it should onely be a matter of getting to the GridChannels node and then looping through it's GridChannel children.

Forgive the lack of VBNess, I'm a C# boy

Comment: There's something you aren't telling us then. When you debug what does channelsNode.OuterXml show?